# mySQL Composite Primary Key With One Part of the Key Auto Increment

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

We are looking for a table with "Composite Primary Key" (2 fields together)
In this one field needs to be auto incremented.

```
CREATE TABLE test_table(
  field1 INTEGER,
  field2 INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT,
  field3 INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (field1, field2)
)
```

we use the above code but it throws some error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled auto_increment ;)

Answer (score 1):

The auto-incrementing column has to be the *first* column you specify in the `PRIMARY KEY` definition. Also, you need an underscore (`_`) in "AUTOINCREMENT":

```
CREATE TABLE test_table(
  field1 INTEGER,
  field2 INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
  field3 INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (field2, field1)
)
```

Comment: this is working perfect.   Am looking one more thing.. for each FIELD1 value i need FIELD2 same.................for Field1 = 1,Field2 can be 1,2,3,4,5,6, and Field1 = 2,Field2 can be 1,2,3,4,5,6...........How to implement this?